# Install Android-x86 in Virtualbox VM, then root it

Tags: rooting, root-access, titanium-backup, vm, virtualbox

**Problem**

I want to install Android in a VM to restore a backup using Titanium Backup. For this to work I need Android to be rooted.

**What I tried**

I've tried to install Android-X86 4.3 in a Virtualbox VM. The installation seems to work. I made a 8GB partition disk (sda1), made it bootable, and installed Android in it from an ISO file. This all seems to work. Android starts, I can browse the internet, install apps, etc. Then I want to restart the VM, and guess what?! I go back to the installation screen, like starting up from the ISO live image.

For normal stuff I can make a snapshot, start that up, and do anything. My problem is that I need root permission to restore a Titanium Backup in that VM. And I cannot root this VM because the disk is not writeable. With ALT-F1 I become root, and I can use a script to root Android. But my guess is that I'm still on the ISO and that is not writeable.

**Update - another try with Android 4.2**

As mentioned in the comments, 4.3 would have problems with root access. I tried 4.4, which didn't start at all. Then I tried 4.2, which has the same problem as 4.3 for me. I made a screenshot of what I see when I try to run the [rootscript](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2162360&stc=1&d=1375546952), which is [described here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2390619).

You can see the errors: **rm failed - Read only filesystem**

How can I fix this?

[image]

**My question**

How can I install Android permanently on this VM, so it can reboot and then be rooted?

Comment: If you're talking about Android-x86 in VirtualBox: It usually comes with root access. Except for the 4.3 image, which I also failed to get root access on. You might wish to try a different image then.

Comment: I'm going to try 4.4. It does come with root access, but that only works for the terminal via ALT-F1. It does not mean that the apps can use root access.

Comment: I've got 4.0 (ICS) running in a VM. It has `/system/xbin/su` as well as `/system/app/Superuser.apk`, the latter being for the apps part. Never checked 4.4, but doesn't it have these as well?

Comment: I can't get 4.4 to start up. So I'll give 4.2 a try and hope that works.

Comment: Aside from the rooting, why can't I reboot after installing? Why does it seem like I go back to the live image? Do I miss a step somehow?

Comment: I've updated the question - 4.2 didn't work as well.

Comment: Sure, if `/system` is read-only. On install you can decide to have it read/write by default (which is what I did), makes things easier. You can also `mount -o remount,rw /system` to make it writeable. You might also wish to check first whether `Superuser.apk` does already exist, before you try installing it (I don't remember if I needed to install it or if it already was there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your reboot problem, it sounds like your boot order is booting off the .iso, i.e., cdrom, before it looks for the disk partition where you installed Android. Shut everything down and disconnect the .iso. You can just delete the CD device under the controller within VirtualBox Settings->Storage. You probably shouldn't just change the boot order or you will have trouble reinstalling if you ever need to. However, if you want to change the order, look under Settings->System->Motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

If You set /system as read-write you don't will have any problems at all.
In The Instalation do this :[image]